# Spring boot + spring security + hazelcast session replication could not make it work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, hazelcast

I am trying to introduce spring security to angularjs app. Back end uses spring framework . I used the methodology explained here for back end security.

https://samerabdelkafi.wordpress.com/2016/01/25/secure-angularjs-application-with-spring-security/

This is working fine with single app instance.

The problem is application is clustered and therefore sessions must be replicated .

I tried to use hazelcast for session replication as explained here:

https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-hazelcast-for-session-replication

When I introduce hazelcast , first authenticate is successful. After that the first request is also successfull. But after that  it seems that

org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository can not find the session...

As I said this start to occur after I configure com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter for sesion replication as below:

```
  @Bean
public WebFilter webFilter(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("instance-name", hazelcastInstance.getName());
    properties.put("sticky-session", "true");

    return new WebFilter(properties);
}
```

Here are the related logs:

2017-08-22 15:17:31,593 : [DEBUG] [http-nio-7023-exec-2][HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository]  No HttpSession currently exists

2017-08-22 15:17:31,593 : [DEBUG] [http-nio-7023-exec-2][HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository]  No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.

I am sure that client sends the same cookie after successfull login

I could not figure out the reason. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I wrote the DZone article you referenced. Happy to help you diagnose. Are you able to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ? eg. on Github or similar

Comment: Did you figured out how to make it work on your side?

Comment: Did you get this working @simpleusr ?

Comment: @NeilStevenson Unfortunately not ...

Comment: Any chance of a smaller more complete example ? On github perhaps ?

Comment: @NeilStevenson Hi Neil, unfortunately I am working on proprietary software and can not provide more detail.. However I am trying to use spring session. I will let you know if I could make this work.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/hazelcast-spring.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make this work by using spring session..

https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/java-hazelcast.html

The sessions are successfully replicated between two instances behind a round robin load balancer. Many thanks to spring session developers...